# How to understand when user actually modified the value using react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I use `watch`, and `useWatch` to know when user changes the state, but it trigger handler on initial load (when default value is applied to form) so there is no difference if user interacted with input or not.

I need to reset the field2 state when and only when user changed field1. But as handler triggered on initial load there is no way to handle it properly.

I have tried to reset field2 only if `formState.isDirty` (so it's definitely changed by user) but during watch/useWatch handler work `isDirty` sill has old value.

```js
  const defaultValues = useMemo(() => {
    const o = Object.assign({}, dummyOrder, pick(order, orderFormFields))

    if (o.services?.length) {
      o.services.forEach(s => {
        s.key = nanoid()
      })
    }

    return o
  }, [order])

  const formContext = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'all'
  })

  const wPro = useWatch({
    control: formContext.control,
    name: 'professional',
    defaultValue: defaultValues.professional
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!wPro) return

    setServices(wPro.services)
    if (formContext.formState.isDirty) {
      formContext.setValue('services', [])
    }
  }, [wPro])
```